# Dynamic binding in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have a little confusion with ***Dynamic Binding*** in java.
Here is a program, I want to know that, is there dynamic binding occurs or something else.
What dynamic binding actually is?

```
class A {
int a;

public A() {
    a = 9;
}

public void show() {
    System.out.print("show in A ; ");
    System.out.println("a : " + a);
}
}
public class B extends A {
public B() {
    a = 8;
}

public void show() {
    System.out.print("show in B ; ");
    System.out.println("a : " + a);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    B p = new B();
    p.show();

    A q = new B();
    q.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I confused you previously.

Dynamic (or late) binding is how polymorphism is implemented in Java. It occurs any time an instance method is invoked.

In your example, we are interested in the occurrences here

```
p.show();
```

and here

```
q.show();
```

At compilation time, the static type of the variable will be checked to see if the method `show()` is accessible, failing if it is not.

At runtime (dynamic), the run time (dynamic) type of the object will be checked to find an implementation of the method. If one is found, it is used, if not, the JVM keeps looking up the inheritance hierarchy.

For example

```
A q = new B();
q.show();
```

at run time, `q` is of type `B` and `B` overrides `show()` so `B#show()` is invoked.

---

In your answer I had commented on, the overriden method did not play a part. It was more a question of constructor execution order.

Answer (score 4):

It's here

```
 A q = new B();
 q.show();
```

Compiler uses virtual call instructions (`invokeVirtual` or `invokeInterface`) for methods which can be overriden (they cannot be static or private). In this code JVM detects that `A.show` is virtual and checks the actual type of `q`. Since it is `B` it calls `B.show`. If it were static JVM would call `A.show` and we would see

```
show in A
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `show()` invoked in the below lines

```
A q = new B();
q.show();
```

The target object of the show method is determined at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

you can change it in your main method to implement polymorphism or dynamic binding:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();       
    a.show();

    a = new B();       
    a.show();
}
```

as you can tell that even the reference is never changed `A a` but what it refer is changed, as different instance it point to, difference behavior will be done!
This is so called `polymorphism`.

Much powerful polymorphism, after using `reflect` in java will indulge you! have fun!

Answer (score 0):

**- Binding** is **act** of `method call identifying and calling its method body`.

**- Java** only supports Dynamic Binding, **except few exception cases**.

**-** The **compiler can't** understand which `method call` to be associated with which `method body`... so its the **responsibility of the method call** to associated itself to its appropriate method body.

**-** Its very important to know that `Fields` (Instance Variables) are **NOT POLYMORPHIC IN NATURE.**

**In your case the Dynamic binding is here:**

```
 A q = new B();
 q.show();
```